# Ratio of thermal energy in a parcel of water between two time periods (metric vs imperial units)

Tags: thermodynamics, dimensional-analysis, units

I am having a problem figuring out something that should be quite basic with determining the ratio of the thermal energy content of a parcel of water (let's say $1 kg$) in between two time periods and units with a temperature change. Could you set me straight on this?

I believe the equation for this is :

$$E = m × c × T$$

where,

$ E = \rm thermal \ energy$

$ m = \rm mass$

$c = \rm thermal \ heat \ capacity$

$ T = \rm temperature$

So, current (time $t_1$) for 1 kg of water at $\rm 10 °C (283 K)$ is :

$$E_{t_1} = m × c × T_{t_1}$$

And at time $t_2$ it is $\rm 15 °C (288 K)$ :

$$E_{t_2}= m × c × T_{t_2}$$

So the ratio :

$$\frac {E_{t_2}}{E_{t_1}} = \frac {m × c × T_{t_2}}{m × c × T_{t_1}}$$

$m$ and $c$ in the ratio cancel so the ratio is dimensionless.

And is ;

$\frac {T_{t_1}}{T_{t_2}}=\frac {15}{10} = 1.5$

Now , if you do this in imperial units with Fahrenheit it is the same equation (and granted $c$ and $m$ are in appropriate imperial units) but $m$ and $c$ cancel regardless and therefore the ratio is :

$\frac {59}{50} = 1.18$

Do I have the equation correct and if so, why is the ratio different?

I understand that Fahrenheit is scale shifted from $c$ (there is an intercept that is not zero) but I do not understand why the ratio is not the same if thermal energy content units are $\rm BTU/lb$ or $\rm kJ/kg$ because $m$ and $c$ just cancel in the ratio.

Comment: For imperial, you have to use Rankine.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the temperature in degrees *Celsius* or *Fahrenheit* in this equation, as $T$ is a *thermodynamic temperature* which means *Kelvins* only! You should be using temperature in Kelvins in general when dealing with equations in physics. The *"problem"* with temperatures in degrees Celsius or Fahrenheit is that they have an affine component which is not linear.

An exception to this rule is if an equation contains a temperature difference, such as $T_1 - T_2$. In this case you could use either Kelvins or degrees Celsius, but not degrees Fahrenheit! This is because the affine component in degrees Celsius (273.15 $^\circ$C) will cancel, but degrees Fahrenheit also have a scaling component which does not cancel by differentiation.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. So this implies to me that the units of thermal energy content have temperature dimension attached to them e.g. kJ/kg K. I am still confused though because is there not a a conception of thermal energy content (ability to do work) that would be the same for a parcel of water regardless if temperature were measured in C or F or K? If not, it implies to me that a kg of water at 283 K, 10 C or 50 F have different amounts of thermal energy in them.

Comment: @dand The thermal heat capacity indeed has a dedicated unit and it is $\text{J/kg K}$. Again, forget about degrees Celsius and Fahrenheit - those are good only for a weather forecast.